# Watir browser.goto opens a second window

Tags: ruby, http, watir-webdriver, goto

I'm writing a script to go to an HTTPS encrypted page.  When I manually type the name of the page into the browser, it brings up the page as I would expect.  When I go to it via a Watir script, it opens a second browser window, with the same address as the first, but with a blank.htm page rather than the login.aspx that I am expecting.  I have not been able to find any clues why this would behave differently when scripted vs when I bring up the page in the browser myself.

I'm using Windows 7, and IE 9.

The script is very basic, and works fine with other pages.  The page I'm having trouble with uses HTTPS and the address takes me through an SSL proxy server.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new:ie
b.goto 'https://secure.ourdomain.com/app/login.aspx'
```

At this point, I have one browser window pointing at the page I opened in the script and one pointing at https://secure.ourdomain.com/app/blank.htm.   The page should not be popping up another window, and with normal usage, it does not, just when I open it via the Watir script.

Can anyone make any suggestions for getting this to stop, or at least some things to try for troubleshooting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read your question, and imagine someone asking you that question and giving you that information. Could you make sense of it and answer it? What would you need to know? Would a short summary of the HTML being encountered help? As is, there's really not enough to help us help you. Please see "[Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" for a list of questions to ask yourself.

Comment: How about: `Watir::Browser.start 'https://secure.ourdomain.com/app/login.aspx', browser: :ie` ([docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Browser))

Comment: Tin Man, I wasn't sure what part of the source page HTML is the cause, and it's fairly lengthy, so I wasn't sure if I could post the whole thing.  I was hoping someone with experience would see a pattern with the HTTPS if that was part of the cause, or at least maybe someone has seen a difference in behavior between "live" and scripted.  What I will likely need to do is try to recreate the problem with a simplified page.

Comment: @Greg Burgardt, that doesn't seem to work.  I assume I need the require 'water-webdriver' before that Watir::Browser.start.  I get NameError: undefined local variable or method `browser' for main:Object
        from (irb):2
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I also found in your docs link the following: browser = Watir::Browser.start "www.google.com", :ie    I added my URL to it, and it does the same thing as the .goto, I get two windows, one with my url, and one with the blank.htm.

Comment: Just wondering if you have tried another browser and if you are experiencing the same issue with, say, Firefox or Chrome.